# Eloquent - Consulta para obtener un registro sin ciertos campos

Tags: laravel, eloquent

estoy trabajando con Laravel 5.8. No se si se puede hacer lo que quiero...

Si para obtener un Usuario dada su ID, puedo usar la consulta:

```
User::find($user_id);
```

Y para obtener solo *nombre* y *email* del usuario:

```
User::find($user_id, ['nombre','email']);
```

¿Hay una consulta que me devuelva el usuario **omitiendo campos concretos**, por ejemplo la fecha de creación (created_at)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay para Eloquent un metodo para ocultar la salida de uno o varios atributos, se llama `makeHidden($attributes)` y lo colocas despues de la busqueda del `find()`

Aqui te coloco un ejemplo que hice en el tinker ocultando los atributos, created_at y updated_at:

```
$a = User::find(4);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$a = User::find(4)->makeHidden(['created_at','updated_at']);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede apreciar en la ultima salida ya no envia los atributos ['created_at','updated_at'].

Espero que pueda ser de ayuda...

adjunto el link de la fuente:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-collections#available-methods

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza el método `select` es la mejor opción para traer solo la información necesaria,

```
 User::select('nombre','email')->find($user_id);
```

En todo caso puedes seguir incluyendo los valores que necesites obtener, quiza tambien necesites el `id` entonces:

```
 User::select('id','nombre','email')->find($user_id);
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. ¿Por qué es mejor usar el método `select`?

Comment: @Orici, Simple ya que con `makeHidden` una consulta seria mas o menos asi;  `select * 
 from user where id=1` y posterior laravel se encarga de buscar los hidden, en cambio con `select` la consulta seria asi; `select id,nombre,email from user where id=1 ` y listo.

Comment: si te he entendido bien: con `makeHidden()`, se hace la consulta obteniendo todos los registros y posteriormente se eliminan los campos que se le indican antes de devolver los resultados, mientras que con una consulta  con `select()` indicando los campos a devolver, solo se hace una consulta solicitando esos campos y se devuelve el resultado, siendo en este último caso el proceso más eficiente, ¿correcto?

Comment: @Orici, en cuanto a eficiencia dependera mucho de la cantidad de datos que tengas, muchos dicen que no existe diferencia cuando los datos son menores a 5000000 fila (aprox) en la tabla consultada, pero con superiores el tiempo de respuesta cambia significativamente(en laravel) y todo depende de que las consultas con ORM esten bien planteadas, existe un articulo completo sobre esto si lo encuentro o publico.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el metodo `select` para incluir los campos que necesitas.

```
User::find($user_id)->select('nombre','email')->get();
```

Dejo la documentación del query builder paara que la revices. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#selects

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero no es lo que preguntaba, ya se varias formas de traer unos campos concretos. Un saludo.